# Run Mock Server in standalone with Expectations

Tags: java, mockserver

I am able to run Mock Server using command line with Java, but I am not able to find a way to pass an Expectation for it.

```
java -jar mockserver-netty-3.10.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar -serverPort 1080
```

I know that with Maven plugin it may be possible, but I want to use plain and pure Java initialization. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no current option for running Mock Server as a standalone Java application with expectations.

[Running From Command Line - Using Java](http://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/running_mock_server.html#running_from_command_line_using_java)

Answer (score 1):

There's an option to set up expectations on startup. Here's an example from the [docs](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/initializing_expectations.html#expectation_initializer_json):

```
java -Dmockserver.initializationJsonPath="org/mockserver/server/initialize/initializerJson.json" -jar ~/Downloads/mockserver-netty-5.12.0-shaded.jar -serverPort 1080 -logLevel INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Postman.
To create expectations:
1)Go to Postman.
2)For creating expectations send a PUT request to
"http://localhost:portnumber/mockserver/expectation".
3)Go to the browser and click "http://localhost:portnumber/mockserver/dashboard" to
access the mock server.